# jenkins Wipe out repository and force clone vs Clean before checkout

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to understand the difference between the two options “Wipe out repository and force clone” and “Clean before checkout” for pulling a git repo. Looking at the help section for both options, both seem to have similar functionality and I can't make out the difference. Here's how they look:

> Wipe out repository & force clone:
>
> > Delete the contents of the workspace before building, ensuring a fully fresh workspace.
>
> Clean before checkout
>
> > Clean up the workspace before every checkout by deleting all untracked files and directories, including those which are specified in .gitignore. It also resets all tracked files to their versioned state. This ensures that the workspace is in the same state as if you cloned and checked out in a brand-new empty directory, and ensures that your build is not affected by the files generated by the previous build.

I couldn't find any comparison between the two options; neither in Jenkins/GitPlugin wiki, nor in stack overflow, and not even in google. We currently have both options, but we are planning to reduce build time by removing the “Wipe out repository and force clone” option. But I don't want to break any functionality while doing this. Please explain the difference if you're sure. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Wipe out repository & force clone** will clean the entire project workspace and clone the project once again before building. It could be time consuming depends on the project size. If the project is 1GB, it downloads 1GB everytime you build it.

**Clean before checkout** removes the files created as part of build - say your test results etc - resets the files if they were updated  & pulls the latest changes if they have been updated. **This ensures that the workspace is in the same state as if you cloned and checked out in a brand-new empty directory**. It downloads only the delta which could be few MBs. So it is less time consuming.

So you can go ahead use **Clean before checkout** without affecting the build.
Have been using this option for more than 4 years without any issues.

Comment: Thanks, but to make my question more specific: is the end result same in both cases?

Comment: @Siddardha : Mostly you are good with "clean before checkout" .   I use clean after checkout. So I checkout fails, I still has a working tree for quick check).  Deleting entire workspace  is useful if you have repository corruption problem(we face that once in a while .. probably due to large size @ 30G)

Comment: @Siddardha, yes the end result is same.

Comment: @Siddardha We currently noticed a difference in files which are inside .gitignore

Build process gets some dependencies from third party (in our case using composer which extracts this to directory vendor)

Now we removed a dependency and only with "Wipe out repository & force clone" the folder was really removed.

With "Clean before checkout" files/folders inside .gitignore are not removed. In 90% this is okay, except you want to remove stuff.

Comment: One other thing I just noticed now. It does `git clean -xdf` so not `git clean -xdff` which keeps repositories that were cloned inside.

Comment: We have a project where in each build, Jenkins merges the PR with the current develop. In order for this to work, I've had to use Wipe out and force clone. When using Clean before checkout, we have pmd and checkstyle issues get reported that have nothing to do with the current PR. I'm not sure why this is, but thought I'd provide my experience between the two.

Comment: Only time I've needed "Wipe our repo and force clone" is when you create a branch with a name that's a sub-part of another branch with slashes

e.g. you created `test/things` and then `test`

`test/things` then blocks you creating a local ref for `test` because it occupies the file path in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

**Clean before checkout** does not update the local branches so any command in the job involving merging branches may fail.

In our case, one of the jobs included the execution of the jgitflow plugin to create a new release. It usually works as expected but in one case we had to implement a hotfix with the corresponding update of the `master` branch and  because of this, next time we run the release job it failed because the local branch in the job's workspace was outdated.